# Rewrite nonconvex problem as "nested" convex problem

Tags: terminology, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

Suppose that we wanted to minimize a function like $f(x,y)=(x-sin(y))^2+(y-3)^2+4$. Notice that $f$ is nonconvex. For each fixed $y$ define $g_y(x)=f(x,y)$. Notice that each $g_y$ is convex. Let $h(y)= min_x g_y(x)$. Notice that $h$ is convex and that the minimum of $h$ is the same as the minimum of $f$. My questions are as follows:

1. Is there a name for functions like $f$ that are not convex themselves but can be solved in this manner?
2. Is there a name for this technique of optimizing over one subset of variables first, and then over the complementary set of variables?

Comment: Coordinate wise descent.

Comment: It is not clear to me that $h$ is convex. How did you establish that?

Comment: @MichaelGrant Each $g_y$ is convex quadratic, with minimum at $x=sin(y)$. So $h(y)=(y-3)^2+4$, which convex quadratic.

Comment: @copper.hat  this is not exactly coordinate descent (at least as I understand it). I never minimize $f$ over $y$. I think if one tried coordinate descent on this function starting far from the min, it would take a long time to reach to solution, or may even get stuck before it gets there. On the other hand, my method involve one convex problem within another convex problem, so the convergence should be very quick.

Comment: It is hard to give an exact answer to a broad question in 3 words :-).

Comment: I still don't see it. How is the $sin(y)$ term eliminated?

Comment: Oh nevermind, I see it now. Carry on. ;-)

Comment: But is this a contrived example or one that you found genuinely useful? I question how common it is for partial minimization of a non-convex function will yield a convex result. And of course, what works here depends rather critically on the fact that you've minimized over $x$ analytically.

Comment: @MichaelGrant I am interested in family of problems for which I think this technique could possibly work, but I can't prove it. That's why I was hoping to put a name to it, so that I could research it further

Comment: Also, we could minimize over x numerically, as long as we are willing to solve a minimization problem for each evaluation of h.

Comment: There are many techniques that involve minimising over subsets of variables, but I don't know of a general term.

Comment: Well yes, you could minimize over $x$ numerically, but because it's nonconvex you can't guarantee you'd hit the global minimum unless you use an exhaustive technique. And as the number of nonconvex variables increases... In fact, if I were to do this numerically I might minimize over the *convex* variables first, and apply the global optimization technique to that result.